# How to adapt the discrete-time to continuous, $(A) \Rightarrow (B)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, riemannian-geometry, ergodic-theory

in class  was proved oseledets theorem for discrete time, following guidelines Ricardo Mañe book.

**Theorem discrete Oseledets (A) :**

Let $ M ^ n $ be a Riemannian manifold, $ f: M \rightarrow M $ be a diffeomorphism of class $ C^1$ and $\mu$ invariant probability measure for $f$. For $\mu$ a.e  $ x \in M $ there are real numbers $\lambda_1(x)>\ldots >\lambda_r(x)$ and decomposition $T_xM=E_1(x)\oplus \ldots \oplus E_r(x)$ such that  $$\displaystyle{\lim_{ k \rightarrow \pm \infty }\frac{1}{k}\log\Vert Df^k(x)u\Vert=\lambda_j(x)}$$ 
for all $u\in E_j(x)\backslash \lbrace 0\rbrace$ and  $1\leq j\leq r$.

I am curious if this result can be adapted to flows. Let me know if my reasoning is correct:

**Theorem continuous Oseledets (B) [I think this should be]:**

Let $ \phi: \mathbb{R}\times M \rightarrow M $ a flows and $d\phi_x^t: T_xM \rightarrow T_{\phi^t(x)}M$ where $ \phi^t=\phi(t,.):  M \rightarrow M $ then $\mu$ a.e  $ x \in M $ there are real numbers $\lambda_1(x)>\ldots >\lambda_r(x)$ and decomposition $T_xM=E_1(x)\oplus \ldots \oplus E_r(x)$ such that 
$$\displaystyle{\lim_{ t \rightarrow \pm \infty }\frac{1}{t}\log\Vert d\phi_x^tu\Vert=\lambda_j(x)} \ \ \ (*)$$ 
for all $u\in E_j(x)\backslash \lbrace 0\rbrace$ and  $1\leq j\leq r$.

Also appreciate any suggestions to prove this assertion (B), in particular the existence of limit (*) using the result (A).

Comment: It is a standard and illuminating exercise to carry out this deduction for oneself. Hint: try applying the discrete-time MET to the time-one solution map. Does applying $d\phi^s_x$ for $s \in [0,1]$ affect the asymptotic growth rates of vectors?